# Type of update on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions

New to Postgres and PL/pgSQL here.

How do I go about writing a PL/pgSQL function to perform different actions based on the type of update (insert,delete,etc) made to the table/record in a postgres database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be looking for **a trigger**.

In SQL, triggers are procedures that are called (fired) when a specific event happens on an object, for example when a table is updated, deleted from or insterted into. Triggers can respond to many use cases such as implementing business integrity rules, cleaning data, auditing, security, ...

In Postgres, you should first define a PL/pgSQL function, and then reference it in the trigger declaration.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_table_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $my_table_trigger$
    BEGIN
        ...
    END
$my_table_trigger$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER my_table_trigger
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON mytable
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_table_function();
```

From within the trigger code, you have access a set of special variables such as :

- `NEW`, `OLD` : pseudo records that contain new/old database records affected by the query
- `TG_OP` : operation that fired the trigger (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, ...)

Using these variables and other triggers mechanisms, you can analyze or alter the on-going operation, or even abort it by raising an exception.

I would recommend reading Postgres documentation for [the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtrigger.html) and [Trigger Procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/plpgsql-trigger.html) (the latest gives lots of examples).

Comment: Thanks you.Is there anyway to achieve this without the use of a trigger.?

Comment: @vva : if you want to execute some code when a specific event occurs, triggers are the way to go. Else, you can create stored procedures and calls them from your application. Finally, you can also handle all the logic in the application.